# Configure GRADLE to use CC compiler on SunOS 11

Tags: gradle, sunos, solaris-studio

Is it possible to use GRADLE with Solaris Studio CC/cc compiler on SunOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gradle allows addition of native tools toolchains :

https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/docs/src/samples/native-binaries/tool-chains/build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which C compiler Solaris uses, but you have GCC and CLang that are supported by Gradle, see [the doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/native_software.html#native-binaries:tool-chain-support)

**Edit**: According to this [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E60778_01/pdf/E68116.pdf), mostly (there are exceptions) you can mix Solaris C compiler and GCC which would lead me to say that (mostly) Solaris C compiler is supported with Gradle

Comment: Thanks, aware of the supported compilers, but our application uses Solaris native "CC" compiler, and i am not able to find any information about any plugin etc for integrating SunOS compiler with Gradle.

Comment: Solaris C compiler seems more or less gcc compatible so I'd think that gradle would (more or less) support Solaris C compiler

Comment: Thanks Adonis, gradle has officially stopped support for Solaris OS's